# I have got this warning: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;

Tags: java

This is my sample code where i am getting the warning.

```
Class aClass = Class.forName(impl);
Method method = aClass.getMethod("getInstance", null);
item = (PreferenceItem) method.invoke(null, null);
```

The warning:

> warning: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
>   cast to java.lang.Class for a varargs call
>   cast to java.lang.Class[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning
>      Method method = aClass.getMethod("getInstance", null);

please help me solve this problem

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Well, the compiler warning tells you everything you need to know. It doesn't know whether to treat `null` as a `Class<?>[]` to pass directly into `getMethod`, or as a single `null` entry in a new `Class<?>[]` array. I suspect you want the former behaviour, so cast the `null` to `Class<?>[]`:

```
Method method = aClass.getMethod("getInstance", (Class<?>[]) null);
```

If you wanted it to create a `Class<?>[]` with a single null element, you'd cast it to `Class<?>`:

```
Method method = aClass.getMethod("getInstance", (Class<?>) null);
```

Alternatively you could remove the argument altogether, and let the compiler build an empty array:

```
Method method = aClass.getMethod("getInstance");
```

Comment: Thanks Jon that warning has been goon............ I have just change my code as you suggest aClass.getMethod("getInstance");

Comment: If anyone was wondering (like me), it seems to default to treating the null as the whole array `Class<?>[]`, not a single null element inside an array (at least according to answers posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028059/calling-java-varargs-method-with-single-null-argument). Of course, it's probably best practice to cast for specificity, but it's good to know when considering whether to refactor methods that take an Array as the last argument into varargs.

Comment: Where in the JLS is the rationale for the fact that in this example a cast to `Class<?>` would produce an array with a single `null` element?.

Comment: @JaimeHablutzel: Because `Class.getMethod(String, Class<?>)` doesn't exist - so the first two phases in 15.12.2 wouldn't find any method to call. With varargs, it works because there *is* a variable arity method `Class.getMethod(String, Class<?>[])` - see 15.12.2.4. The array is constructed as per 15.12.4.2, with the argument (value null) being the sole element in the array.