# Java varargs with single argument gives "unclear whether varargs call or not" despite cast

Tags: java, generics, variadic-functions

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401537/i-have-got-this-warning-non-varargs-call-of-varargs-method-with-inexact-argumen), and it should solve my problem, but I still get a `Confusing argument '(Class<?>[])null', unclear if a varargs or non-varargs call is desired` warning here, in both cases:

```
public class MultiArgument<T, E> implements Argument {
    private final Argument[] args;
    private final Class<T> type;
    private final New<T, E> maker;

    public MultiArgument(E enclosingInstance, Class<T> type, Argument... args) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        this.type = type;
        this.args = args;
        this.maker = New.create(enclosingInstance, type,
                (Class<?>[]) (ArrayUtils.<Argument, Class<?>>transform(args, Argument::getReturnType))); // here
        New.create(null, null, (Class<?>[])null); // and even here.
    }
...
}
```

`New.create`:

```
public static <T, E> New<T, E> create(E enclosingInstance, Class<T> type, Class<?>... argTypes) throws NoSuchMethodException {
    return new New<>((Class<E>) enclosingInstance.getClass(), enclosingInstance, type, argTypes);
}
```

And the full New.java, just in case: http://pastebin.com/rtCVkiGX

Comment: Which tool gives this warning? I have never seen such a warning from the javac compiler itself.

Comment: @Codebender IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: I am not sure about were exectly you get the warning but I  overcame similar ones by using new `new String[]{null}` instead of null.

Comment: @c0der I am getting it at the line that has `// and even here.`, on the line directly before that, I get a very similar warning: `Confusing argument '(Class<?>[]) (ArrayUtils.<Argument, Class<?>>transform(args, Argument::getReturnType))', unclear if a varargs call or non-varargs call is desired`.

Comment: @c0der, `new String[]{null}` is not the same as `(String[]) null` which is what the OP seems to be doing and probably needs.

Comment: @Codebender `new String[]{null}` is not proposed as a replacement to ` (String[]) null` but a solution to avoid the warming when trying to set null argument to `String...args`.  In the OPs case `new Class[]{null}` might be a more appropriate example.