# Why should I explicitly cast null for the invocation of a varargs method?

Tags: java

I've got the following code:

```
public static void varargsMethod(String ... strings) {
    if (strings != null && strings.length != 0) {
        for (String s : strings) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Hello (string free) world!");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    varargsMethod(null);
    varargsMethod((String[]) null);
    varargsMethod((String) null);
    varargsMethod();
}
```

I wonder why the first invocation with null as the argument generates a warning with the hint, that an explicit cast is needed. From the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028059/calling-java-varargs-method-with-single-null-argument) it is not clear for me, why this cast is needed. The first two invocations work and produce the same result, while the third produces "null". I explicitly want the behaviour of the first two invocations.

Shouldn't null be always valid (and automatically casted) for reference types and arrays? I don't see, why the type information is important in this case.

**Edit:** Updated the code with a variant with no arguments at all. I definetly need to differ between the three cases (no array and empty array handled in the same way; array with null value in another). I wonder if there's a better way than checking for null and empty array.

Comment: Doesnt the linked answer cover it? Since it cant decide if `null` is the array itself or the first value in the array.

Comment: I just edited my question. I would like to have `null` as the array instead of the first value. I believe it doesn't has to decide, because it's still possible to get the latter behaviour.

Comment: Why would you *want* to pass in a null array? That sounds like a case where you'd want a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Personally I don't want to pass in a null array myself. Nevertheless, I can't give a guarantee for future users. Shall I take care of this or is it ok, if they are punished with a NullPointerException on wrong usage?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just that `null` is implicitly convertible to any type, so in your case it's ambiguous. All of these are possible:

```
varargsMethod((String[])null); // pass in a null reference
varargsMethod(new String[]{null}); // pass in a single-element array
varargsMethod((String)null); // equivalent to previous
```

so the compiler is encouraging you to specify which one you mean.

Comment: Isn't `varargsMethod(null)` more clear (and less verbose) than casting it? Do you know if it's just a design decision or a technical reason?

Comment: I'd say it's a technical reason

Comment: If your goal is to call with no parameters at all, an alternative method I prefer from a readability standpoint is to simply call `varagsMethod()`. It doesn't set strings to null, but rather to an empty array. Your varargsMethod can then be cleaned up a bit by leaving out null checks for strings (assuming you don't want users to be allowed to pass an explicitly cast null array)

Comment: @Bengt: Actually, I think I would have expected that `varargsMethod(null)` meant `varargsMethod((String)null)`, since the point of a varargs method is that you can, and usually do, supply the elements of the array rather than the array itself. I've been assuming that the *only* reason it means `varargsMethod((String[])null)` is that the designers wanted strict backward-compatibility for any varargs methods that, before Java 5, used to take explicit array arguments, and that backward-compatibility required the implicit selection of `String[]` rather than the more-intuitive `String`.

Comment: @helloworld922: Note that the OP's method is defined in such a way that passing a `null` array reference is *not* equivalent to passing in an empty array. (That's arguably a design mistake, though.)

Comment: @ruakh: Thank you for pointing out that you expected I mean `(String)null`. I realized that null as the first argument does make more (or equivalent) sense. I just updated the question. Is there a better way to deal with the different ways of invoking the method?

Comment: @Bengt: I think that if a null array is a valid use-case, then you don't actually want a varargs method. People think of varargs methods as taking a "variable number of arguments, maybe even zero" -- not "a variable number of arguments, or maybe some other option that's not a number of arguments at all". It's misleading to use varargs when you're really thinking of the array itself as the argument, such that null could make sense.

Comment: @Bengt You're missing the point. You may find it clearer. The compiler just finds it ambiguous, under the resolution rules define din the JLS.