# How can I mock constructor with varargs using PowerMockito?

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito

I have a bean:

```
class Bean {
    public Bean(String name, Integer number, Resource... resources ) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I want to mock constructor of the bean. Here is my test:

```
@Test
public void shouldReturnMockedBean() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.whenNew(Bean.class)
                .withArguments(
                        Mockito.anyString(),
                        Mockito.anyInt(),
                        Mockito.<Resource>anyVararg()
                ).thenReturn(beanMock);

        Bean bean = new Bean("abc", 1);

        Assert.assertNotNull(bean);
}
```

I also use `PowerMockito` annotation in my test class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({Bean.class})
```

But I get an error a `null` instead of my mock. What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631596/how-to-properly-match-varargs-in-mockito

Comment: In your question, can you please put a comment on the line of code that has the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **varargs is getting set to null** instead of creating a varargs where the first element is null.

To fix it, do `Bean bean = new Bean("abc", 1, (Resource)null);`

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028059/calling-java-varargs-method-with-single-null-argument)

If you meant to provide no Resources, however, then just omit the 3rd parameter.

Comment: I need to test constructor `new Bean("abc", 1)` where varargs in empty.

Comment: Do you still get the error when you do the constructor that way?

Comment: No, if i leave it, test will pass.

Comment: Great! There's your solution then :)