# Why does Arrays.asList(null) throw a NullPointerException while Arrays.asList(someNullVariable) does not?

Tags: java, variadic-functions

This small program

```
public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Arrays.asList(null);
    }
}
```

throws a `NullPointerException`.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:221)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.<init>(Arrays.java:4322)
    at java.base/java.util.Arrays.asList(Arrays.java:4309)
    at org.example.Client.main(Client.java:10)
```

This program, however,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Arrays.asList(returnNull());
}

private static Object returnNull(){
    return null;
}
```

does not. Why do they behave differently?

Comment: I think it has something to do with the method returning a null `Object` reference, while the plain old null is different? Intrigue question

Comment: Nice one,  in the second case the parameter is interpreted as an array of size 1 containing  a `null` value , and in the first case as a `null` array . Don't know why and how, though.

Comment: Thanks @sotirios-delimanolis for formatting

Comment: Related (or even a duplicate): [Calling Java varargs method with single null argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4028059/calling-java-varargs-method-with-single-null-argument)

Comment: `Type...` represents array of `Type` elements and since `null` can be assigned to any reference type it is OK for compiler to allow `Type... array = null`. But It is not OK to allow `T... array = someObject;` because `someObject` may not always hold value which can be assigned to `Type... array` (like `null`). So what compiler must do to make `T... array = someObject;` safe for all values? Simplest solution are often best so here simplest one is to add code which would wrap passed element in array like `Type... array = new Type[]{someObject}` regardless of actual value of `someObject`.

Comment: @Lino Well found. I do believe it's a duplicate

Comment: @Michael I refrained from hammering it myself, but if you also think it is one, then well done. Just didn't want to ego this :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The difference is just about how the argument is used at runtime:

The signature of `asList` is

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)
```

`Arrays.asList(returnNull())` calls it with an `Object`. This *clearly* does not get interpreted as an array. Java creates an array at runtime and passes it as an array with one `null` element. This is equivalent to `Arrays.asList((Object) null)`

However, when you use `Arrays.asList(null)`, the argument that's passed is taken to be an array, and, as the the method explicitly fails on null arrays passed as argument (see `java.util.Arrays.ArrayList.ArrayList(E[])`), you get that NPE.

Answer (score 1):

Signature of asList() is :- `public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)`

So args requires Array of type T.

1st Case: When you put `null` as arg in asList the array will be pointing to null therefore throwing Exeption.
2nd Case: When you return a reference to any object which is pointing to `null`. Then it means array having a single Object, and that Object is pointing to `null` therefore not throwing Exception.